# Julia: extracting clustering indices

Tags: julia, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am using julia's Clustering package to obtain `dbscan` clustering results on the output of UMAP, but I am stuck in trying to get cluster indices from the DBscanresult data structure. My goal is to pass cluster indices as a vector for a 2D scatter plot, but I could not find a way to obtain this vector from dbscan results.

Julia implements two methods under dbscan. I am using the [adjacency list implementation](https://juliastats.org/Clustering.jl/latest/dbscan.html), which takes the n x d array of point coordinates (umapresults, below).

```
db = dbscan(umapresults, .1, min_neighbors = 10, min_cluster_size = 10)
```

producing the results:

```
13-element Array{DbscanCluster,1}:
 DbscanCluster(17, [4, 12, 84, 90, 94, 675, 676, 737, 873, 965], [27, 108, 177, 880, 954, 1050, 1067])
 DbscanCluster(10, Int64[], [46, 48, 51, 57, 188, 225, 226, 228, 270, 542])
 DbscanCluster(11, [48, 51, 228], [46, 49, 57, 188, 225, 226, 270, 542])
 DbscanCluster(14, [418, 759, 832, 988, 1046], [830, 831, 855, 865, 989, 991, 996, 1021, 1070])
 DbscanCluster(10, Int64[], [624, 654, 664, 803, 805, 821, 859, 987, 1057, 1069]) ...
```

But ACAICD there isn't a direct method to obtain unique cluster indices from these results.

Ideally, I would like an implementation that produces unique assignments:

```
assignments::Vector{Int}: vector of clusters indices, where each point was assigned to a single cluster
```

This method actually exists and is implemented for the 'distance matrix' version of dbscan, but nothing equivalent exists for the 'adjacency list' implementation.

Your insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @nils-gudat I found the answer that works for me. TIL that I have to broadcast `getproperty()` to the resulting structure with a dot after `getproperty.()`. There are three fields for the resulting structure `DbscanCluster` in `dbscan()` for the adjacency list method, these are:

### DBSCAN

cluster returned by dbscan function (point coordinates-based implementation)

### Fields

- `size::Int`: number of points in a cluster (core + boundary)
- `core_indices::Vector{Int}`: indices of points in the cluster core
- `boundary_indices::Vector{Int}`: indices of points on the cluster boundary

There is no 'assignment', as in the distance based matrix method, so if I have to return the `core_indices` vector via broadcasting:

```
getproperty.(drb, :core_indices)
```

Which gives me the array i was looking for:

```
7-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [3, 33, 35, 36, 37, 45, 60, 63, 67, 68, 69, 219, 263, 273, 274, 453, 454, 547, 560, 1077]
 [5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24  …  1094, 1095, 1097, 1098, 1099, 1100, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105]
 [6, 179, 199, 223, 344, 345, 346, 350, 353, 355, 379, 385, 388, 389, 416, 423, 430, 447, 562, 565]
 [29, 66, 133, 138, 141, 164, 171, 181, 194, 250  …  702, 883, 887, 990, 997, 998, 1015, 1055, 1056, 1074]
 [86, 103, 140, 160, 207, 251, 253, 275, 284, 298  …  958, 993, 994, 999, 1002, 1004, 1005, 1024, 1072, 1092]
 [418, 759, 802, 804, 818, 819, 830, 831, 832, 855  …  988, 989, 991, 995, 996, 1021, 1046, 1047, 1049, 1070]
 [502, 518, 806, 822, 829, 850, 912, 964]
```